# Add previous load count using the the present count and the timestamp column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following columns

```
id, timestamp, current load count, previous load count
```

and it has many rows. I have values for all the first three columns, but for the "previous load count", I need to get the count of the date one day before the count of the current load count.

See the below image (table example) to view the sample table

For example: previous load count of id:4 is the count same as the current load count of id:5.

Is there anyway to write a SQL statement to update the previous load count?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT [id] 
      ,[timestamp]
      ,[current load count]
      ,LAG([current load count]) OVER (ORDER BY [timestamp] ASC, [id]) AS [previous load count]
FROM [table]
```

The [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function can be used to access data from a previous row in the same result set without the use of a self-join.

It is available after SQL Server 2012.

In the example I added ordering by `id`, too - in case you have records with same date, but you can remove it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you need *exactly* one day before, consider a `join`:

```
select t.*, tprev.load_count as prev_load_count
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.timestamp = dateadd(day, -1, t.timestamp);
```

(Note:  If the timestamp has a time component, you will need to convert to a date.)

`lag()` gives you the data from the *previous row*.  If you know you have no gaps, then these are equivalent.  However, if there are gaps, then this returns `NULL` on the days after the gap.  That appears to be what you are asking for.

You can incorporate either this or `lag()` into an update:

```
update t
    set prev_load_count = tprev.load_count
from t join
     t tprev
     on tprev.timestamp = dateadd(day, -1, t.timestamp);
```